# Constrain Data Based on Implicit Relationships in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, database, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, relational-database

I have generalized the problem as outlined by the **Data Model** and **Data**. My generalization only keeps the relationships in tact.

## The Problem

We have a **base** model `Owner`, which captures the `Pet` for the owner, in this way we can look at all owners and determine if they are a `Cat` or `Dog` owner.

We have separated *Owners* based on their `Pet` into two tables: `CatOwner` and `DogOwner`. These tables are where unique details are captured for each owner type.

In the specific tables, `CatOwner` and `DogOwner`, we collect the information `PetType` so we can determine if their pet is: *Grumpy*, *Friendly*, *Cute*, etc...

The business has defined what `Type` each `Pet` can be in the `PetType` table.

## The Question

> Is there a mechanism in **Entity Framework Core** that allows us to constrain the data in a manner which won't allow a `CatOwner` to have a `PetType` where the `PetType.Pet = Dog`?

I understand that an option for this is to add `CatType` and `DogType` tables to the data model, then a `CatOwner` will have a `CatType` and a `DogOwner` will have a `DogType`. This solution will require adding a generic type to the data model architecture which I don't want to do, since this is such a small piece of the overall data model. We will enforce this relationship in the API, but there won't be any [Referential Integrity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/primary-and-foreign-key-constraints?view=sql-server-ver16#referential-integrity) enforced by the database engine.

We don't leverage the [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/types-and-properties). We rely heavily on [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/#use-data-annotations-to-configure-a-model) which is our preferred technology for defining relationships.

### Data Model (Pseudo-Code Overview)

```cs
Pet {
    Id
}

Type {
    Id
}

PetType {
    Id,
    PetId,
    TypeId
}

Owner {
    Id,
    PetId
}

CatOwner {
    Id,
    OwnerId,
    PetTypeId
}

DogOwner {
    Id,
    OwnerId,
    PetTypeId
}
```

### Data

`Pet`

| Id |
| --- |
| Cat |
| Dog |

`Type`

| Id |
| --- |
| Grumpy |
| Selfish |
| Friendly |
| Helpful |
| Cute |

`PetType` (These relationships are defined by the business)

| Id | Pet | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Cat | Cute |
| 2 | Cat | Grumpy |
| 3 | Cat | Selfish |
| 4 | Dog | Cute |
| 5 | Dog | Friendly |
| 6 | Dog | Helpful |

### Data Model (Details)

```cs
[Index(nameof(PetId), nameof(TypeId), IsUnique = true)]
class PetType
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    Pet? PetNavigation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PetNavigation)]
    int PetId { get; set; }

    Type? TypeNavigation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(TypeNavigation)]
    int TypeId { get; set; }
}

class Owner
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    
    Pet? PetNavigation { get; set; }
    
    [ForeignKey(nameof(PetNavigation)]
    int PetId { get; set; }
}

class CatOwner
{
    int Id { get; set; }

    Owner? OwnerNavigation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(OwnerNavigation)]
    int OwnerId { get; set; }

    PetType? PetTypeNavigation { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(PetTypeNavigation)]
    int PetTypeId { get; set; }
}
```

I have come up with other viable solutions which will be implemented in the case that this path is a dead end. Right now I am just exploring options and looking for new ways to approach the problem.

Comment: Why not have separate `CatType` and `DogType`?

Comment: @Charlieface, having separate `CatType` and `DogType` tables is an option for sure. Right now I'm trying to figure out if **EF Core** has a mechanism to do what I want. -- Otherwise I will add the two "Type" tables and modify the data model architecture.

Comment: Entity Framework Core does not directly support the kind of constraint you are describing using Data Annotations alone.it might help you with some basic checking. you could try using the database trigger based approach. Use SQL database trigger to enforce this constraint. Any insertion or update that violates your constraints would be rejected by the trigger.

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, You answered my question. Thank you!

Comment: @JalpaPanchal, I will be happy to mark this as the **Answer** if you decide to post it as an answer rather than a comment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entity Framework Core does not directly support the kind of constraint you are describing using Data Annotations alone.it might help you with some basic checking. you could try using the database trigger based approach. Use SQL database trigger to enforce this constraint. Any insertion or update that violates your constraints would be rejected by the trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Why even have tables such as CatOwner and DogOwner? You'll need a table for each type of pet. Just use a junction table:

[image]

Comment: the `CatOwner` and `DogOwner` allow capturing specific/distinct data for the two types of owners, essentially, both `CatOwner` and `DogOwner` inherit `Owner`. For some reason I can't see the picture you linked in your answer, but I did look up junction tables, thanks!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL--text.

Comment: Then remove the image option if it doesn't work and the functionality isn't coded correctly...